# What coin is this and where is it from? Thai script, Thai arms. Rev: left facing portrait

Tags: identification, numismatics

here is the front and back of a coin which I would like to find out about. Anyone know which country this is from? Thank you very much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a 1 [Baht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_baht) coin from Thailand, between 1957 and 1962:

[image]

<sup>Source: [coinquest.com](http://coinquest.com/cgi-bin/cq/coins?main_coin=19971)</sup>

See also ["Reading Thai Numbers and Dates" by Portland Coins](http://portlandcoins.blogspot.de/2013/10/reading-thai-numbers-and-dates.html).